# Program about friendly numbers

Tags: java

I am working on some additional exercises for my introduction to programming class, and I cannot figure out what I did wrong regarding the following question:

> (Friendly Numbers) An integer is said to be friendly if the leftmost
>   digit is divisible by 1, the leftmost two digits are divisible by 2,
>   and the leftmost three digits are divisible by 3, and so on. The
>   n-digit itself is divisible by n. For example, the number 42325 is
>   friendly because 4 is divisible by 1, 42 is divisible by 2, 423 is
>   divisible by 3, 4232 is divisible by 4, and 42325 is divisible by 5.

Write a general method (with or without recursion) with the name
isFriendly that determines whether or not the number is “friendly”
. Write a main method that tests the method isFriendly.

My program is as follows:
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Question4 {

   public static void main(String args[]){

       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
       String input = in.nextLine();

  }
  public static String isFriendly(String input){
        int n = input.length();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
        String output = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<=n; i++){
            if (((n/10*i)%i) != 0 ){

                output = "Friendly";
            }else{

                output = "Not friendly";
            }
            return output;
        }
     }
  }
```

The error given is: "The result must return a result of type String".
What can I do to solve this problem, and can I write this program in a more efficient way? 
Thank you so much for considering this question!

Comment: The method isFriendly doesn't always return a value. You can move the return line after the for loop

Comment: You do have a logic issue, where as long as the last test case is friendly, regardless of previous tests, it will say that the number is friendly.

Comment: as someone said, move the output to after the for loop. What if i<=n never runs? then you will never return a String, which is why this is throwing an error. For a more efficient approach, I would also initialize `String output = "Friendly";`, then return if at any point it is "Not friendly".

Comment: First solve the problem. Then write the code -- John Johnson.

Comment: A plan for a simpler solution: (1) Generate a list of "last n digits" for all n, (3) check them all for divisibility; (3) if all checks pass, the number is friendly. "Last n digits of number k" is `k % 10^n`.

Comment: Because `not all paths return a value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try my code here I use StringBuilder class to get each actual int then convert it to string then convert it to int everytime the loop iterate

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    String input = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println(isFriendly(input));
    }
    public static String isFriendly(String input)
    {
        int n = input.length();
        String output = "";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        int myIntOutput=0;
        for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            sb.append(input.charAt(i));

            if (Integer.parseInt(sb.toString())%(i+1)==0)
            {
               myIntOutput++;

            }


        }
        if(myIntOutput==n)
        {
            output="Friendly";
            return output;
        }
        else
        {
            output="Not Friendly";
            return output;
        }
    }
```

if this help you consider accepting it as an answer

Comment: This works for me, thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: no problem I am here to make StackOverflow a better place by helping others and not be a troll

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public static String isFriendly(String input) {
    if (input == null || input.length() == 0) return "Not friendly";

    int n = input.length();
    int number = Integer.parseInt(input);

    for (int i = 0; i<=n; i++) {
        if (((n/10*i)%i) == 0 ) {
            return "Not friendly";
        }
    }
    return "Friendly";
}
```

Comment: I did it in your way, @rptmat57, but this always gives the output "Not friendly". What can I do to solve this?